# Oracle RAC database jdbc is connecting from different ports

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I'm trying to connect to RAC datatabase (version 11g) using oracle driver ojdbc7 my url descriptor looks like this

`jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION_LIST=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=**myhost**)(PORT=1532)))(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = **myhost**)(PORT = 1532))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=**my_service_name**))))`

**myhost** responds from 6 different ip´s, but there are some ip's connecting to different ports.

Why does this happen?

Is there any way to say using specific port?

Comment: are you using listener scan  ??

Comment: The listener is on port 1532; when the connection is handed off to a DB instance it will use a different port. This is something you should ask about on [dba.se] rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your RAC is not using SCAN.

Single Client Access Name (SCAN) is a feature used in Oracle Real Application Clusters
environments that provides a single name for clients to access any Oracle Database running
in a cluster. You can think of SCAN as a cluster alias for databases in the cluster. The benefit is that the client’s connect information does not need to change if you add or remove nodes or databases in the cluster.

**SCAN was first introduced with Oracle Real Application Clusters (RAC) 11g Release 2** and provides additional functionality in Oracle RAC 12c. Having a single name to access the cluster to connect to a database in this cluster allows clients to use EZConnect and the simple JDBC thin URL to access any database running in the cluster, independently of the number of databases or servers running in the cluster and regardless on which server(s) in the cluster the requested database is actually active.